# Ruby on rails application backed with MySQL database crashes on Heroku with a error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I create a new app in ruby on rails backed with mysql database. But when I try to run the app, it crashed with the following error message:

```
Running `rails console` attached to terminal... up, run.1388
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:315:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:121:in `<class:PredicateBuilder>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:70:in `block in eager_load!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:70:in `each_value'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb:70:in `eager_load!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record.rb:159:in `eager_load!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:142:in `require_application_and_environment!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/bin/rails:8:in `require'
from /app/bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

I don't understand the first line of error itself. I configured the app to run on MySQL database but it says PostgreSQL specified. I am a newbie, can you help me debug my app. It's just a basic app created by the command:

```
rails new myFirstApplication
```

No changes were made to it.
Here is my database.yml file which is configured to use mysql:

```
default: &default
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
pool: 5
username: root
password: 80517326A!
socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development:
 <<: *default
 database: myFirstApplication_development

test:
 <<: *default
 database: myFirstApplication_test


production:
  <<: *default
  database: myFirstApplication_production
  username: myFirstApplication
  password: <%= ENV['MYFIRSTAPPLICATION_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Comment: Heroku does not work with mysql, it only works with postgres.

Comment: @BroiSatse Ohh I see! Is it somehow possible to use MySQL in development environment but use postgreSQL in production environment(i.e. in Heroku)? If so, how?

Comment: You can do this, however I would not recommend this - MySQL behaves differently than PostgreSQL in many aspects and sth that works in development might not work in production.

Comment: @BroiSatse Thanks, this solved my problem! :) If you could, Post your comments as an answer so that I can choose it as my solution!

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately heroku requires `PG`. There are workarounds, you can point your `DATABASE_URL` to a remote location where you can use mysql, but it's advisable to use postgres in development and production mode if you're planning to deploy to heroku.

Check this out: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#write-your-app

Answer (score 0):

Just add `pg` gem for production environment in your Gemfile, thats it:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

No need to change your `database.yml`. Heroku don't use application's `database.yml` for database connection. It uses PostgreSQL for which your app should have `pg` gem. Heroku will creating database settings on the fly.